# How to fix lack of finish in a v60 with very acidic grounds

Tags: brewing-process, v60

I just got a new batch of beans and am having trouble brewing a cup with a decent finish. The flavor on my cups just seems to disappear in a matter of seconds after actually drinking.

I searched online and that seems to be an indication of under extraction. With that in mind, I ground a bit finer which, despite massively increasing drawdown time, didn't fix the issue.

I'm using James Hoffman's recipe of 15g/250g, 45 sec bloom

Some notes on the beans, which I suspect might help:

- Brazilian origin (yellow/red catuai)
- Natural process
- Floral/citrus notes, which I kinda get, but not much
- Roasted Jan 20th

Should I just push the grind finer still? Are the beans just more conducive to a quicker finish and I just discovered that they're not my favorite? Something else?

It should be noted that with my previous brews this didn't seem to be an issue. So I doubt that my grinder, albeit cheap (crushgrind colombia) is the culprit.

What I did try already, with varying degrees of success:

- Making sure the water is as hot as possible by reapplying heat when waiting for the bloom and pouring straight from the boiler
- Increasing the ratio by about 10% (my scale only has 1g sensitivity)

This added *some* finish to the coffee, but not near what I get with different beans.

The more I experiment, the more I'm convinced I'm just not a fan of this particular bean profile flavor because I'm starting to get some bitterness which would indicate that I'm actually overextracting now.

Comment: Welcome to Coffee! Did you try increasing the coffee to water ratio? That could solve underextraction but it might also cause overextraction. What temperature is the water you're using? Is it straight off the boil or do you let it cool a bit? Trying a few more recipes (brew ratio and water temperature) could help identify the issue.

Comment: I did try both, I'll update the question with the answers to your questions thank you!